# Parametric equation of line conceptual doubt

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

I was studying the parametric form of equation of a line and I am facing problems with some signs.

$$\frac{x-x_1}{\sin\theta}=\frac{y-y_1}{\cos\theta}=r$$

Now I am always having problem regarding the sign of r whether it's $+r$ or $-r$ whenever I don't know the distance between any two point.

For example I want to find the equation of a line such that its segment between the line $5x-y+4=0$ and $3x+4y-4=0$ is bisected at $(1,5)$

Now if I write two equation using the point $(1,5)$ with which line should I use $+r$ and $-r$ is unclear and hence I don't know what to do in such situation. Can you please suggest me a way to easily figure out how I should chose my $r$.

Comment: $r$ is taken to be positive by convention. You can have negative $r$, but that is almost never used.

Comment: @Nameless  But in the problem I mentioned above, the right answer came up when I took one of the $r$ to be negative. How to sort that out?

Comment: Can you describe the problem from the text? I have no idea what is is looking for.

Comment: @Nameless I have made the necessary edit. You can look the question up there.

Comment: I don't understand why you need polar coordinates. You can do this in Cartesian. You need to find the intersection point first. And since the point is to the right of the intersection point, you just make a line segment that is bisected exactly at (1,5). I'll even get you started: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5x-y%2B4+%3D%3D+0,+3x%2B4y-4+%3D%3D+0

Comment: @Nameless I know I can do it that way and I have already done it using Cartesian system. But I want to know how can I apply the parametric form to find the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43588/discussion-between-harsh-sharma-and-nameless).